# AWS SNS Subscription Filter policy checking a key in Message Attributes does NOT exist - possible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, publish-subscribe, amazon-sns

We have two types of SNS messages coming in:

**1.** has MessageAttributes empty like this:

`"MessageAttributes": {}`

**2.** has MessageAttributes coming in like this:

```
                "MessageAttributes": {
                    "Generator": {
                        "Type": "String",
                        "Value": "some-service"
                    }
                }
```

I would like to use a filter subscription policy that ignores the second type but passes the first type to the subscriber.

So I tried this for the policy:

```
{
  "Generator": [
    {
      "exists": false
    }
  ]
}
```

I thought this would mean it will only pass along messages that do NOT contain the `Generator` key in `MessageAttributes`

However I am seeing now that no messages are getting passed along.

The AWS Subscription Filter docs seem to support this as a solution, but they only show the opposite way of checking that a key does exist, so I'm not sure if they support checking a key doesn't exist: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-subscription-filter-policies.html#attribute-key-matching

Is this possible?

Comment: You can always reverse the logic on the other side when you publish. It will be helpful if you can also post the publish method and its arguments.

Answer (score 2):

The answer from @David Adams is out of date. See the [Attribute key matching](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/attribute-key-matching.html) docs.

> Use "exists": false to return incoming messages that don't include the specified attribute.

It is now possible to exclude any messages that have a particular key by using the policy:

```
{ 
  "key": [
    {
      "exists": false
    }
  ]
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Late response but may be helpful to someone.

Filtering out by lack of existance is not possible. See the bottom of https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-subscription-filter-policies.html#attribute-key-matching

`Note: You cannot use the exists operator to match messages in which an attribute does not exist. Filtering will NOT match any messages if you set [{"exists": false}].`

You could pass a string 'null' or similar to the generator attribute if it is non existant maybe?

Comment: This is fubar. Like why the f is that needed? The whole reason you want to look for exist: false is to catch any situation and not leave anything hanging. Now you need to have a SQS collecting all messages and removing all the ones manually that does have any of the attributes you're checking against to be able to select the ones that could have been solved with exists:false... SMH